# How to get the certificate path from a BinarySecurityToken?

Tags: java

I have received a SOAP response that contains a BinarySecurityToken in the header. I have created a X509Certificate based on the BinarySecurityToken.

Do you know how I can determine if this X509Certificate is trusted?

For example, how would I determine from the certificate what its certificate path is?

Note: we are using a java standalone client as our webservices client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to do this yourself, the JRE already does it for you.  Check out the X509TrustManager which can be acquired via the TrustManagerFactory.

Comment: If I got an X509TrustManager from a TrustManagerFactory for a given trustStore, how would I use this to test if the X509Certificate (from BinarySecurityToken) was trusted?

Comment: I would suggest you spend some time reading the API docs and try it out first.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

certToVerify.verify(‌​parent.getPublicKey()‌​),

where certToVerify is the X509Certificate created from the BinarySecurityToken, and parent is the X509Certificate from the truststore (signer of the certToVerify certificate).